# Trying to dynamically use regex findall to pick up registry keys. How to append single escape to regex string?

Tags: python, regex

`test_str = Monitor for deletion of Windows Registry keys and/or values related to services and startup programs that correspond to security tools such as HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\AMSI\\Providers. Monitor for changes made to Windows Registry keys and or values related to services and startup programs that correspond to security tools such as HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender.`

```
for path_found in iocs_found['windows_path']:
   path_found = path_found.replace('\\', '\\\\')
   print(path_found)
   regex_pattern = f"[A-Z]+(?:{path_found})" 
   matches = re.findall(regex_pattern, test_str)
   print(matches)
   print('\n')
```

print statements are:

M:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AMSI\Providers.

['HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AMSI\Providers.']

M:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows

['HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows']

Two questions:

1. how do I change my regex code so that `HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows` becomes `HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender`
2. how to add a new regex to the current dynamic regex so that there aren't double escapes?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular input you showed above, the pattern `HKLM:\\.*?(?=\.)` should work:

```py
test_str = "Monitor for deletion of Windows Registry keys and/or values related to services and startup programs that correspond to security tools such as HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\AMSI\\Providers. Monitor for changes made to Windows Registry keys and or values related to services and startup programs that correspond to security tools such as HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender."
matches = re.findall(r'HKLM:\\.*?(?=\.)', test_str)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\AMSI\\Providers',
 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender']
```

Comment: thanks! but is it possible to add the regex pattern dynamically? I have a dictionary of other patterns to choose in the event its not a windows registry, so a dynamic regex pattern is a requirement for me.